# Capsule shape detection in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection

I have a [binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wldLv.png) and I'd like to detect all approximately capsule-shaped regions like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPR4h.png) (marked in red).

The size and orientation of desired regions is different for each image and unknown.

The desired ratio of height and width is between 3 and 5.

I don't know how to detect shape with unknown orientation and size, so I tried to use the ratio of the region's area and its bounding box's diagonal squared as criterion, but the result is not very good. Here's the code I use.

```matlab
regions = bwconncomp(img);
sizes = cellfun(@numel, regions.PixelIdxList);
N = regions.NumObjects;
is_capsule = false(N, 1);

for k = 1:N

    idx = regions.PixelIdxList{k};
    [row, col] = ind2sub(sz, idx);
    h = max(row) - min(row) + 1;
    w = max(col) - min(col) + 1;
    l = numel(idx) / (h^2 + w^2);

    if l >= 0.1 && l <= 0.2
        is_capsule(k) = 1;
    end

end
```

Comment: Use regionprops with 'MajorAxisLength' and 'MinorAxisLength' properties.
Select element if   3<'MajorAxisLength'/ 'MajorAxisLength'<5